# Good book on capital flows?

Tags: reference-request, open-economy-macro, capital-mobility

Are there any good textbooks/books for capital flows?

I have found some from searching online, but they are a bit older:
International Capital Flows by Feldstein in 1999
Capital Flows and Crises by Eichengreen in 2002

I am wondering if there is anything out there that is more recent?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some recent books:

- [Taming Capital Flows: Capital Account Management in an Era of Globalization](https://www.bookdepository.com/Taming-Capital-Flows-Joseph-E-Stiglitz/9781137427663) (2015)
- [Capital Flows and Exchange Rate Management](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/capital-flows-and-exchange-rate-management-9780198075455?cc=us&lang=en&) (2013)
- [Managing Capital Flows: The Search for a Framework](https://www.adb.org/publications/managing-capital-flows-search-framework) (2010)
- [Capital rising: how capital flows are changing business systems all over the world](https://www.palgrave.com/us/book/9780230612310) (2010)